# How to find min in mongodb for a nested object?

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('mapinfo').find().min({"bounds.south":0})
```

When I use the above code to access south in bounds object It errors out to 'BadValue'. Is it possible to access the nested object in min method. But in find method it works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.geofftech.com/content/finding-min-and-max-values-mongodb/) blog post, `min` might not work the way you expect it to:

> In MongoDB, the min() and max() functions work as limitors - essentially the same as “gte” (>=) and “lt” (<).

Taking the example from the article, you should be able to use the following instead:

```
db.getCollection('mapinfo').find().sort({"bounds.south":1}).limit(1)
```

This orders the collection so that the minimum value appears first and returns only that first value.